# How to filter census data (From API) with a created list of zipcodes?

Tags: python, pandas, api, census

I pull the data from the census api using the census wrapper, i would like to filter that data out with a list of zips i compiled.

So i am trying to filter the data from a pull request data of the census. I Have a csv file of the zip i want to use and i have it put into a list already. I have tried a few things such as putting the census in a data frame and trying to filter the zipcode column by my list but i dont think my syntax is correct.

this is just the test data i pulled,

```
census_data = c.acs5.get(('NAME', 'B25034_010E'),
           {'for': 'zip code tabulation area:*'})
```

```
census_pd = census_pd.rename(columns={"NAME": "Name", "zip code tabulation area": "Zipcode"})
```

```
censusfilter = census_pd['Zipcode'==ziplst]
```

so i tried this way, and also i tried a for loop where i take census_pd['Zipcode'] and a inner for loop to iterate over the list with a if statement like zip1 == zip2 append to a list.

my dependencys

```
# Dependencies

import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import pprint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests
from census import Census
import gmaps
from us import states

# Census & gmaps API Keys
from config import (api_key, gkey)
c = Census(api_key, year=2013)

# Configure gmaps
gmaps.configure(api_key=gkey)
```

as mentioned i want to filter out whatever data i may pull from the census data specific to the zipcodes i use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how your data looks like. I am guessing that you have a scalar column and you want to filter that column using a list. If it is the question then you can use `isin` built in method to filter the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col': [2, 3, 4], 'col2': [1, 2, 3], 'col3': ["asd", "ads", "asdf"]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
random_list = ["asd", "ads"]

df_filtered = df[df["col3"].isin(random_list)]
```

Comment: whoa, ill have to try this when i get back in i actually went ahead and did what the first solution was, which was to cast the list to a dataframe then merge. After that i dropped all NaN values and have a df with the template i want

Comment: So this actually worked once i convered my one frame into the same dtype. it is less lines and looks a little cleaner doing it this way!

Answer (score 0):

The sample data isn't very clear, so below is how to filter a dataframe on a column using a list of values to filter by

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Example data
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
'''zip,some_column
"01234",A1
"01234",A2
"01235",A3
"01236",B1
'''), dtype = {"zip": str})

zips_list = ["01234", "01235"]

# using a join
zips_df = pd.DataFrame({"zip": zips_list})
df1 = df.merge(zips_df, how='inner', on='zip')
print(df1)

# using query
df2 = df.query('zip in @zips_list')
print(df2)


# using an index
df.set_index("zip", inplace=True)
df3=df.loc[zips_list]
print(df3)
```

Output in all cases:

```
     zip some_column
0  01234          A1
1  01234          A2
2  01235          A3
```

Comment: i did not even think to cast the list to a dataframe, i was able to merge and then drop all values that didnt line up so this worked for me. Thanks